# Real quick question

Tags: idioms, adjectives, adverbs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can “real” be used as an adverb to describe an adjective?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/714/can-real-be-used-as-an-adverb-to-describe-an-adjective)

Let me just ask you something real quick. Is my previous sentence wrong? Must the real part be "really"?

Some context: I am asking, because "real quick" sounds cool as hell and I see more and more people using it.

Comment: As the answers have noted, *real quick* is informal and more likely to be encountered in American than British contexts. In fact, standard British English requires: '(Let me just ask you something) *really quickly*.'

Comment: This is a _real_ _cool_ summary of the answers below. +1 :D

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's not wrong, but it's informal.

The *[Free Merriam-Webster Dictionary](https://web.archive.org/web/20220704115806/http://merriam-webstercollegiate.com/dictionary/real)* has this to say:

> Most handbooks consider the adverb *real* to be informal and more suitable to speech than writing. Our evidence shows these observations to be true in the main, but *real* is becoming more common in writing of an informal, conversational style. It is used as an intensifier only and is not interchangeable with *really* except in that use.

Comment: Oxford is compelled to add *chiefly North American*.

Comment: This is known as ["Conversational Deletion"](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/66994/15299) and it's very common in informal, intimate talk. Anything predictable at the beginning of an utterance (like _I have a_ or _do you have time for a_ here) gets deleted; because it's predictable, it doesn't need to be said. Most stuff like this is fixed phrases, complementizers, auxiliaries, prepositions, and other nuts-n-bolts rubble from constructions. Anything written is ambiguous, but speech (and dialog in writing) uses it well.

Comment: @JohnLawler: I think you may have posted your comment in the wrong place? I don't think the use of *real* as an adverb is an instance of conversational deletion; even if we regard it as deletion of *-ly*, it doesn't meet the "sentence initial position" requirement.

Answer (score 5):

As ruakh wrote, it's informal.

> Is my previous sentence wrong? Must the real part be "really"?

This seems to be from American English, so the answer will depend on use. I have heard Americans use the word *real* like this. It would not necessarily be wrong for someone speaking American English. The word should be "really" for people speaking the British kind of English.

Which version to use will depend on which English you speak.

Comment: Um, this gives a different perspective from the other answers up to now. But can you back up your statement about correct in American and wrong in English languages?

Comment: It's not so much about correct or wrong. It's about use. I'm in the UK and have not heard any English (or other British person) say real, in a sentence like that. I have heard it from Americans that I have met and seen on television.

Comment: Useful to know. You've got +1 from me. I accept the other answer, as it states sources, but yours adds to that a lot.

Answer (score 3):

No it's not wrong. It's an informal form of the adverb *really* and *very* used as a submodifier.

> My tooth hurts *real* bad,
>
> My tooth hurts *really* bad, and
>
> My tooth hurts *very* bad

all mean the same thing.

Comment: My tooth hurts really badly.  Not "bad".

Comment: @David- you might be right. But the same usage is in wide use. Give it a google search and see for yourself.

Comment: @david- I think you are right. It sounds strange to me as well. But I am not going to edit it unless you think it's necessary:)

Comment: Sure, but when the whole thread is about the grammaticality of using an adjective in place of an adverb, I felt it behooved me to point out that both the original question and your example contain two such usages, not just one.

Answer (score -1):

If you drop the real/really, you are left with:

```
A) Let me ask you something quick.
```

which COULD be right if it were two separate thoughts:

```
B) Let me ask you something; quick!
```

but that doesn't seem to be what you mean. Sentence A should be:

```
C) Let me ask you something quickly.
```

If we wanted to modify the adverb quickly, we would use another adverb, "really," so it should read:

```
D) Let me ask you something really quickly.
```

That is the most correct form. It's also the most formal. If you want to sound informal (arguably American), go with "real quick;" otherwise, really quickly.

Comment: Actually; *let me ask you something quick* could mean the same as *let me ask you a quick question*, which is unexceptionable by any standard.  But yes, in British English the adverbs are *really*, and *quickly*

Comment: "Let me ask you something. Quick." is a valid interpretation, and the only valid way to read the sentence as is. Also, "really" and "quickly" are adverbs in America too, so let's all stop toting our "British is better" for one minute.

Comment: How on earth can you say 'the only valid way' to interpret sentence A is to insert a full stop?  And that *real* and *quick* can be adverbs in American English but not in British English is a fact, not a value judgement.  Could you please read what I wrote, not what you expected?