# The use of "real" in the following cases

Tags: adjectives, word-usage, adverbs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Real quick question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/72896/real-quick-question)

> If you listen real close...
>
> Can you swing by real quick...

Sentences like the above two are what I often hear in daily life. If I didn't hear them in the real world, I would probably be more ready to say "If you listen really close..." and "Can you swing by really quick...".

Is *real* being used as an adjective in this scenario? If so, is the usage of adj.+ adj. a common practice in English language?

Comment: No, it's being used as an adverb. The _-ly_ ending gets dropped pretty frequently in real speech. Since it's simply an emphasizer like _very_, it doesn't really matter whether it's there or not.

Comment: How about real real? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uyJHzvHwKas

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As intensifiers (words that make an adjective stronger), the adjective form of a word (without the *ly*) is used very often instead of the adverb form in English. As some of the other answers and comments have remarked, these words are indeed adverbs because they modify adjectives.

For example:

> *bloody stupid* (U.K.),
>   *wicked cold* (Boston),
>   *dead certain*.

If you said *bloodily stupid* in England, *wickedly cold* in Boston, or *deadly certain* pretty much anywhere, it would sound real funny. People say *real hot* but don't often say *real true,* because *real* is an intensifier in the first but not the second. ([See Google Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=real+hot%2C+really+hot%2C+real+true%2C+really+true&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)).

Comment: I see nothing whatever wrong with *deadly certain*; and I am in deadly earnest.

Comment: @WS2 'Deadly sure' doesn't sound too good.

Answer (score 10):

There is a comprehensive article looking at various aspects (including historical preferences and shifts) of adverbs-that-resemble-adjectives ***[here](http://www.jamiechavez.com/blog/2011/12/do-not-go-gentle-into-that-good-night/)***; it cites other good sources. The question of which of these so-called **flat adverbs** are licensed by some style guides is also partially addressed. I'd just add here that sometimes, flat adverbs have a different sense from their related -ly forms:

> We went to Rome, and then flew directly on to Rio. (ie as quickly as possible).
>   We flew direct to Rio. (ie without landing mid-journey).

The use of the -ly-less form is best usually regarded as informal though, in my opinion.

Addressing your second question, I'd reiterate that I think it's about time degree modifiers:

> He drove a real(/ly) fast car.
>   He's plumb loco.
>   He drove real(/ly) fast.

and other 'secondary modifiers':

> It was chillingly realistic.
>   Time passed excruciatingly slowly.

were recognised as having very different functions from words modifying verbs.

Comment: That's right. To the extent it matters, part of speech has to do with syntactic function, not meaning.

Answer (score 5):

It is an adverb, because it is modifying the intensity of the verbal phrase, not the noun. In this case, it is no different than "very," most commonly used as an adverb.

Answer (score 4):

*[Real](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/real_5)* here is used as an adverb here meaning *very*. This usage is mostly informal and American.

Answer (score 0):

The correct full form of these phrases is to add '-ly' to *both* words, making them form one adverbial section:

- "If you listen real close..." → "If you listen really closely..."
- "Can you swing by real quick..." → "Can you swing by really quickly..."

Comment: Are you somehow thinking that *close* and *quick* are never **already** adverbs, and so need an *-ly* suffix to make them become such? That needn’t be true. Here we have *quickest* used in the sense of what you would probably prefer were written “most closely”: §1840 Dickens *Barn. Rudge* x, ― *“The person who’d go **quickest**, is a sort of natural.”* And here we have *closer* for what you probably think needs to be *more closely*:  §1833 Thirlwall, in *Philol. Museum* II. 160 ― *“The **closer** they are examined, the more suspicious do they appear.”* Those are both adverbs, you realize.

Comment: @tchrist: Well, those are comparative and superlative forms, and there aren't distinct adverbial comparative or superlatives, so people mostly just use the adjectival form. At least, that's my reading of it.

Comment: Flat adverbs (without the *-ly*) were common in the days of Shakespeare. Since then, they appear to have fallen out of use to a large extent in the U.K., but are still relatively common in the U.S. From Shakespeare: *where you shall take your rest // For this one night; which, part of it, I'll waste // With such discourse as, I not doubt, shall make it // Go quick away;* **and** *Follow me close, for I will speak to them.*

Comment: In formal discourse your answer would be quite correct. Observe, however, that OP [the original poster] is asking about what he or she "often hear[s] in daily life". We are dealing therefore with the colloquial register, which generally evolves more quickly than the formal register. We must be careful of these distinctions here; it is likely that the proposed [Learner's](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners) will focus more narrowly on Standard English.

Comment: How? Those are the inflectional degrees of adverbs, just like *who runs faster* and *who runs fastest are*, or *what dives deeper* or *what dives deepest*. They aren’t “using adjectives”. Those are real adverbs.  It doesn’t take an *-ly* to make an adverb. People oftenly think thusly, but it is seldomly soly.

Comment: @tchrist: Will you be mentioning sources of energy that work soly panelly next?