# Why is 'real' and 'really' interchanged?

Tags: word-usage

I thought 'real' was an adjective and 'really' was an adverb?

Is it not improper usage to say things like, "I think the cake is *real* good" ?

Or to have a [news] websites called http://www.realclearpolitics.com/, which I suppose could be correct, though my brain does't process it right away. I'm inclined to think it is attempting to say *really clear politics* and not *real, clear politics*

Is this heavy usage and interchangeability of 'real' and 'really' something of the twitter era?

Comment: Try googling *flat adverb*. Opinion varies from "this is a common mistake" to "this is a perfectly normal locution, particularly in the United States".

Comment: Answered at [The use of "real" in the following cases](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/92178/the-use-of-real-in-the-following-cases) (which was itself closed as a duplicate, but perhaps has a fuller answer).

Comment: OP please check the above post and let us know.

Comment: Notwithstanding anything that the earlier post reveals, dropping the *...ly* from adverbs is more common and more acceptable in America than it is in Britain. Dropping the *...ly* from adverbs is a bit like eating with your fork in your right hand.

Comment: Dropping the -ly (not just for real/really) is perfectly natural in AmE informal speech (but it does sound a little 'youthful' or 'uneducated' (i.e. dropping -ly is grammatical in a certain register, but that register is not considered proper for newspapers. As to whether 'real' is intended as 'actual', or -ly dropped for 'a lot', yes, it's ambiguous but we have no way of knowing the author's true intent.

Comment: The above does answer my question, but my followup would be that am I alone in feeling that the use of real/really in this manner has become more common in the last 7-10 years (i.e. the rise of social media?)

Comment: What has become more common in the past half-century is writing done in close mimicry of spoken English, so that sentences like "We will have a real cool time tonight" (the refrain in the Stooges' song "Real Cool Time" from their 1969 album _The Stooges_) appear more frequently in writing than they used to. But in spoken U.S. English, _real_ for _really_ is exceedingly common and has been so for many decades, though not when educated speakers are on their best behavior.