# Slow or slowly?

Tags: adverbs, flat-adverbs

Is this correct: "I want to start slow, then gradually increase the time I exercise." Or should it say "slowly"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The use of "real" in the following cases](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/92178/the-use-of-real-in-the-following-cases)

Comment: [One of the first questions on this site](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/714/can-real-be-used-as-an-adverb-to-describe-an-adjective)

Answer (score 1):

***Slow*** can be an adverb, and it's called a ***flat adverb***. There are plenty of questions on flat adverbs on this site. I will just add a usage not from the [BritannicaDictionary](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/eb/qa/Slow-Slowly-and-Flat-Adverbs#:%7E:text=Usually%20slow%20is%20used%20as,same%20as%20its%20adjective%20form.):

> Usually *slow* is used as an adjective and *slowly* is used as an adverb, but ***slow*** *can also be used as an adverb*. When an adverb does not have the usual -ly ending it is called a *flat adverb or plain adverb* and it looks the same as its adjective form.
>
> - The cars on the road are all moving ***slow/slowly***.
> - The computer was running so ***slow/slowly*** that he didn't finish his homework on time.
>
> Notice that in the above sentences, the adverb comes after the verb. ***Slow*** and ***slowly*** are usually interchangeable when they come after the verb. However, *when the adverb comes before the verb, it only sounds natural to use **slowly***.
>
> - We ***slowly*** realized what was happening.